# ANDROID - Fragment - Downloading file from Parse backend, saving it in External Storage, then creating Application Chooser

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm working on a Project which used Parse.com as a back-end to share files.
It can successfully share images and videos and can open them. Hence, I don't need them to be downloaded from the cloud.
I was receiving lot of problems for files, but I was finally able to share them after working on them for months.

Now, I still need you people's help.

In my Inbox Fragment, I have listed all the sent files.
But, I want them to be saved into **External Storage** and that the user can be sent to an **App Chooser** to open the file **when it's clicked**
(More Important is to save it in the External Storage.)

I know, It's possible using simple methods. But, The problem here, is that, **its a fragment** where I have on click listener.
Hence, obviously, I'm facing errors as I don't know how to use it in fragment.

Here is my **InboxFragment**.java

```
public class InboxFragment extends ListFragment {

protected List<ParseObject> mMessages;

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    query.addDescendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> messages, ParseException e) {
            getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            if (e == null) {
                // We found messages!
                mMessages = messages;

                String[] usernames = new String[mMessages.size()];
                int i = 0;
                for (ParseObject message : mMessages) {
                    usernames[i] = message.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME);
                    i++;
                }
                if (getListView().getAdapter() == null) {
                    MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(
                            getListView().getContext(),
                            mMessages);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    // refill the adapter!
                    ((MessageAdapter) getListView().getAdapter()).refill(mMessages);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ParseObject message = mMessages.get(position);
    String messageType = message.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE);
    ParseFile file = message.getParseFile(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE);
    Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(file.getUrl());

    if (messageType.equals(ParseConstants.TYPE_IMAGE)) {
        // view the image
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewImageActivity.class);
        intent.setData(fileUri);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        if (messageType.equals(ParseConstants.TYPE_VIDEO)) {
            // view the video
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri);
            intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {

            ParseFile docFile = (ParseFile) message.get("file");
            docFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // data has the bytes for the file
                        //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SaveFileActivity.class);
                        //startActivity(intent);

                        //save the file on external storage
                        public File getAlbumStorageDir(String fileName) {
                            // Get the directory for the user's public downloads directory.
                            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);
                            if (!file.mkdirs()) {
                                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
                            }
                            return file;
                        }

                        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                        List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                        boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        ...

                        // Always use string resources for UI text.
                        // This says something like "Share this photo with"
                        String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
                        // Create intent to show chooser
                        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

                        // Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
                        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            startActivity(chooser);
                        }

                    }

                    else {
                            // something went wrong
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An Error Occured.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I've put the code that was supposed to be in an Activity not a fragment, or is it possible to perform the same here? Or, I have to crete a new SaveFileActivity for this?

This is a snapshot of my InboxFragment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QS2a.png

Here's the **RecipientsActivity.java** where the file is created and sent to the Parse Cloud.

```
public class RecipientsActivity extends ListActivity {

public static final String TAG = RecipientsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mContactsRelation;
protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;
protected List<ParseUser> mContacts;
protected Uri mMediaUri;
protected String mFileType;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipients);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    mMediaUri = getIntent().getData();
    mFileType = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    mContactsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_CONTACTS_RELATION);

    // Add Progress bar here on

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = mContactsRelation.getQuery();
    query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> contacts, ParseException e) {
            // Add Progress bar off

            if (e == null) {
                mContacts = contacts;

                String[] usernames = new String[mContacts.size()];
                int i = 0;
                for (ParseUser user : mContacts) {
                    usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                    i++;
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getListView().getContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                        usernames);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecipientsActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipients, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_send:
            ParseObject message = createMessage();
            if (message == null) {
                // error
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.error_selecting_file)
                        .setTitle(R.string.error_selecting_file_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                send(message);
                finish();
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected ParseObject createMessage() {
    ParseObject message = new ParseObject(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, getRecipientIds());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE, mFileType);

    byte[] fileBytes = FileHelper.getByteArrayFromFile(this, mMediaUri);

    if (fileBytes == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        if (mFileType.equals(ParseConstants.TYPE_IMAGE)) {
            fileBytes = FileHelper.reduceImageForUpload(fileBytes);
            String fileName = FileHelper.getFileName(this, mMediaUri, mFileType);
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile(fileName, fileBytes);
            message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE, file);
        }
        else if (mFileType.equals(ParseConstants.TYPE_VIDEO)){
            String fileName = FileHelper.getFileName(this, mMediaUri, mFileType);
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile(fileName, fileBytes);
            message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE, file);
        }
        else{
            String fileName = FileHelper.getFileName(this, mMediaUri, mFileType);
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile(fileName, fileBytes);
            message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE, file);
        }

        return message;
    }
}

protected ArrayList<String> getRecipientIds() {
    ArrayList<String> recipientIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getCount(); i++) {
        if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {
            recipientIds.add(mContacts.get(i).getObjectId());
        }
    }
    return recipientIds;
}

protected void send(ParseObject message) {
    message.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // success!
                Toast.makeText(RecipientsActivity.this, R.string.success_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecipientsActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.error_sending_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.error_selecting_file_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);




    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                      }
               }
          });      
     }
}
```

Here's the code from **MainActivity.java**

```
protected DialogInterface.OnClickListener mDialogListenerSendFile =
   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             // Choose File
                Intent chooseFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                chooseFileIntent.setType("*/*");
                chooseFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),""));
                chooseFileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);

                startActivityForResult(chooseFileIntent, PICK_DOCUMENT_REQUEST);
    }
};
```

Let me again clarify my question,
1.I'm choosing the file. (in MainActivity)
2.Then, I'm composing sending a file using Parse (in RecipientsActivity)
3.User receives the file (in the InboxFragment)
And, here, is where I want to perform the required action. i.e. (in the inbox fragment) On Click Listener should save the file directly into the External Storage. The, there should open an app chooser to open that file (just after downloading it).
  [Its to be done in a Fragment]
[In the InboxFragment, note that through OnClickListner I've coded for retrieving the image and video and opening them but I don't need them to be downloaded. I want to save a file that has application formats, such as a documents file or contacts file, etc.]

Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: The question isn't super clear. Are you trying to save files that have been sent to the user to external storage or are you trying to select files the user has on their device for sending through your app? The Intent you have in the click listener is an intent for choosing a file from another app. Are you trying to create a file from that choice and then save it in parse?

Comment: why use the parse.file.cloud as a store layer if you are using 'local external.storage' mount as storage for your media? Choose one as a data store and in your apps front end for the media provider, select your media and store it where other Intents from other app (at end of the chooser action) can play it.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to send file from the application, then from click listener, of the inbox fragment, when the other user receives it from the sender, it can be saved into storage and then, the downloaded file is directly sent to another app (through app chooser.) I think I'm much clear now.